# Why the navbar items are not shown?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, navbar, nav

I have the following code and except `Mona Jalal` and a white tiny button next to it in the top right nothing else shows:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-main">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Mona Jalal</a>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-main">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link active page-item" href="index.html">Mona Jalal <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link page-item" href="education.html">Education</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link page-item" href="coursework.html">Coursework</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link page-item" href="teaching.html">Teaching</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link page-item" href="projects.html">Projects</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link page-item" href="honors.html">Honors & Awards</a></li>
                    <li><a class="nav-item nav-link page-item" href="experience.html">Experience</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                    <li><a class="navbar-brand pull-sm-right" href="https://github.com/monajalal"><i class="fa fa-github fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a class="navbar-brand pull-sm-right" href="https://twitter.com/MonaJalal_"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a class="navbar-brand pull-sm-right" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mona-jalal"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a class="navbar-brand pull-sm-right" href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/2414957/mona-jalal"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow fa-lg"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a class="navbar-brand pull-sm-right" href="mailto:jalal@cs.wisc.edu"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a class="navbar-brand pull-sm-right" href="https://www.instagram.com/mona_of_green_gables"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]
I had the following code first, which worked but when I made the screen width to much smaller, things got weird, so I decided to use a button that if you click on it shows the items (like in mobile or say the button you see in the right button corner of Chrome with three lines). The following code actually works but has that problem I said. I am a little lost so if you could give me hints to get going that'll be great :)

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="nav navbar-nav">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link page-item" href="index.html">Mona Jalal <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link active page-item" href="education.html">Education</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link page-item" href="coursework.html">Coursework</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link page-item" href="teaching.html">Teaching</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link page-item" href="projects.html">Projects</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link page-item" href="honors.html">Honors & Awards</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link page-item" href="experience.html">Experience</a>
            <a class="navbar-brand pull-sm-right m-r-0" href="https://github.com/monajalal"><i class="fa fa-github fa-lg"></i></a>
            <a class="navbar-brand pull-sm-right m-r-2" href="https://twitter.com/MonaJalal_"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></i></a>
            <a class="navbar-brand pull-sm-right m-r-4" href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/mona-jalal"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-lg"></i></a>
            <a class="navbar-brand pull-sm-right m-r-6" href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/2414957/mona-jalal"><i class="fa fa-stack-overflow fa-lg"></i></a>
            <a class="navbar-brand pull-sm-right m-r-8" href="mailto:jalal@cs.wisc.edu"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a class="navbar-brand pull-sm-right m-r-10" href="https://www.instagram.com/mona_of_green_gables"><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-lg"></i></a>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

[image]

Please let me know if you would need more details or if the question is not clear enough.

UPDATE: with the second example which is working, the problem is when I reduce the width of the screen it happens to be something like this, as I am new to bootstrap/CSS stuff I am not sure what is the correct terminology to describe the problem but I guess the photos show it best!
[image]

Comment: please provide a jsfiddle link to your problem

Comment: @mona well its normal functionality of nav bar. It will hide all menu bar item in small screen and in big screen it will show full menu. What is the issue then?

Comment: @Leothelion please browse to http://www.monajalal.com and change the width of the screen you will see the issue

Comment: In that site, nav bar is not working.

Comment: @Leothelion navbar is working for me in monajalal.com :O what browser are you using?

Comment: m using firefox. Check in ff too. Well for me its not working in chrome too.

Comment: whew!! not sure what's happening as it working for me. Can you please provide a screenshot? do you have something like a AdBlocker or a weird firewall? http://imgur.com/7FFmdO4

Comment: M getting this error bootstrap.min.js:7 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether

Comment: I have made some changes. please check https://jsfiddle.net/7Lf446p3/1/

Comment: @MonaJalal as far as i can see you are using some plugin or not sure but you have to remove that error if you want your site for normal people as they might not have that plugin so better go with easy build instead of this.

Comment: fixing the errors in your jsfiddle I see this https://jsfiddle.net/monajalal/ouhsaoke/

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by the 'collapse navbar-collapse' CSS classes applied to the 'nav-main' div. Have a look at the bootstrap documentation and see if any of the important notes regarding default navbars (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default) apply in your case.

Comment: Sorry I am very new to the field. I would think a complete answer block would help me better. Any chance you could update your answer?

Comment: Hi Mona, sorry I can't comment on direct questions yet, but I would have posted as a comment only rather than an answer. FYI monajalal.com website navbar looks fine to me when I view from my chrome browser on my cellphone and others comments above seem to indicate the issue is probably browser side. You appear to use chrome, so in chrome you can bring up the developer console by pressing CTRLSHIFT+i. The developer console will be your best friend when debugging problems like this one.

Comment: You should check the console for errors first and see if you have any which may indicate an error on your page. You can also inspect (CTRL+SHIFT+c in developer console) the navbar element to determine if the element is styled correctly, shown/collapsed, and edit the CSS classes of the elements directly to see what may be incorrectly set. I'm sorry I can't give a direct answer but this will hopefully help you get closer to a solution.